# perspective correction example

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have some videos taken of a display, with the camera not perfectly oriented, so that the result shows a strong trapezoidal effect.
I know that there is a perspective filter in ffmpeg https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#perspective, but I'm too dumb to understand how it works from the docs - and I cannot find a single example.

Somebody can show me how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example extracts a trapezoidal perspective section from an input Matroska video to an output video.

An estimated coordinate had to be inserted to complete the trapezoidal pattern (out-of-frame coordinate x2=-60,y2=469).

Input video frame was 1280x720. Pixel interpolation was specified linear, however that is the default if not specified at all. Cubic interpolation bloats the output with NO apparent improvement in video quality. Output video frame size will be of the input video's frame size.

Video output was viewable but rough quality due to sampling error.

**ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.mkv -lavfi "perspective=x0=225:y0=0:x1=715:y1=385:x2=-60:y2=469:x3=615:y3=634:interpolation=linear" output.mkv**

Comment: linear interpolation is making it 'rough'.  cubic / bicubic will make it blurry by more accurately representing sub-pel sample locations.  You can sharpen it after with unsharp=3:3:0.35 if you dislike the softening.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of `ffplay` (or any player which lets you access ffmpeg filters, like `mpv`) to preview the effect, or if you want to keystone-correct a display surface.

For example, if you have your TV above your fireplace mantle and you're sitting on the floor looking up at it, this will un-distort the image to a large extent:

`ffplay video.mkv -vf 'perspective=W*.1:0:W*.9:0:-W*.1:H:W*1.1:H'`

The above expands the top by 20% and compresses the bottom by 20%, cropping the top and infilling the bottom with the edge pixels.

Also handy for playing back video of a building you're standing in front of with the camera pointed up around 30 degrees.